# Auto bordering cells

Tags: excel, vba, border

I'm trying to automatically border any filled cells from P13:S. When the macro runs, I also want it to detect clear cells and remove any borders currently in place. I'm using this at the moment:

```
Set CD = Workbooks("Savant").Worksheets("Client Details")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lngLstCol As Long, lngLstRow As Long

lngLstRow = CD.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lngLstCol = CD.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For Each rngCell In Range(Range("P13:S13"), Cells(lngLstRow, lngLstCol))
    If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
        rngCell.Select
        With Selection.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlNone
        End With
    End If
Next

For Each rngCell In Range(Range("P13:S13"), Cells(lngLstRow, lngLstCol))
    If rngCell.Value > "" Then
        rngCell.Select
        With Selection.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
            .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        End With
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

It's bordering cells as required, but it's failing to remove the borders from empty cells. Can anyone point out where I've gone wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: try len(trim(CStr(rngCell.Value)))=0 as your condition instead....you might have some cells which appears empty but have spaces

Comment: Thanks. It turns out I was just being thick. Replaced the "<>" with a "=" and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code a bit more by combining your logic so that you dont have to loop a second time.

```
For Each rngCell In Range(Range("P13:S13"), Cells(lngLstRow, lngLstCol))
    With rngCell
        If Len(Trim(.Value2)) = 0 Then
            With .Borders
                .LineStyle = xlNone
            End With
        Else
            With .Borders
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
                .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
        End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 0):

I was just being thick. Replaced the "<>" with a "=" and it works as intended. Sorry all.